# Is there a correlation ratio in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, statistics, correlation

Is there any function in Matlab which calculates the [correlation ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_ratio)? 
Here is an implementation I tried to do, but the results are not right.

```
function cr = correlation_ratio(X, Y, L)
ni = zeros(1, L);
sigmai = ni;

for i = 0:(L-1)
   Yn = Y(X == i);
   ni(1, i+1) = numel(Yn);
   m = (1/ni(1, i+1))*sum(Yn);
   sigmai(1, i+1) = (1/ni(1, i+1))*sum((Yn - m).^2);
end
n = sum(ni);
prod = ni.*sigmai;
cr = (1-(1/n)*sum(prod))^0.5;
```

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html or https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/corr.html

Comment: I think the correlation ration is different of the correlation coefficient. I'm looking for this metric: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_ratio

Comment: In that case, you might have to write the function yourself.

Comment: This seems fairly straight-forward to implement, but depends on how you store class labels. Could you share some code that creates an example data set? For example using `randn` etc. Just so we understand the structure of your dataset.

Comment: I tried to implement the function (I edited the question), but the results should lie between 0 and 1, and my results aren't in this range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the equation on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_ratio):

[image: correlation ratio]

where:

- *η* is the correlation ratio,
- *y<sub>x,i</sub>* are the sample values (*x* is the class label, *i* the sample index),
- *y<sub>x</sub>* (with the bar on top) is the mean of sample values for class *x*,
- *y* (with the bar on top) is the mean for all samples across all classes, and
- *n<sub>x</sub>* is the number of samples in class *x*.

This is how I interpreted it into code:

```matlab
function eta = correlation_ratio(X, Y)
X = X(:); % make sure we've got column vectors, simplifies things below a bit
Y = Y(:);
L = max(X);
mYx = zeros(1, L+1); % we'll write mean per class here
nx = zeros(1, L+1);  % we'll write number of samples per class here
for i = unique(X).'
   Yn = Y(X == i);
   if numel(Yn)>1
      mYx(i+1) = mean(Yn);
      nx(i+1) = numel(Yn);
   end
end
mY = mean(Y);        % mean across all samples
eta = sqrt(sum(nx .* (mYx - mY).^2) / sum((Y-mY).^2));
```

The loop could be replaced with [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).